# Google Directions API on Android smartphone returns status code NOT_FOUND

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-directory-api

I want to get JSON information from a route in my Android app using Google Directions API. But I always get "NOT_FOUND" as status code. If I enter the same URL of my request in the browser it works fine.

Here my code inside a AsyncTask:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final String... params) {
        String startAddress = params[0];
        String finishAddress = params[1];
        departureTime = params[2];
        String travelMode = params[3];


        String result = "";
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + startAddress
                + "&destination=" + finishAddress + "&departure_time=" + departureTime + "&mode=" + travelMode + "&sensor=true";
        url = url.trim().replace(' ', '+');

        Log.d(TAG, "URL String: " + url);

        try {
            URL urlObject = new URL(url);
            URLConnection urlConn = urlObject.openConnection();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                result = result + inputLine;
            }
            in.close();

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exception = e.toString();
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception getting route from Google Directions API: " + e.toString());
            Logger.e(context, TAG, "Exception getting route from Google Directions API: " + e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
02-23 08:54:01.811  25055-25055/de.bmw.ceprouteguide D/PlanRouteActivity﹕ startAddress: Hanauer Straße 46, München, endAddress: Westendstraße 11, München, travelMode: transit, date: 23-02-2015, time: 08:54
02-23 08:54:01.812  25055-25055/de.bmw.ceprouteguide D/PlanRouteActivity﹕ Millis since epoch:1424678040, date string: 23-02-2015 08:54
02-23 08:54:01.816  25055-25618/de.bmw.ceprouteguide D/PlanRouteActivity﹕ URL String: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Hanauer+Straße+46,+München&destination=Westendstraße+11,+München&departure_time=1424678040&mode=transit&sensor=true
02-23 08:54:02.116  25055-25055/de.bmw.ceprouteguide D/PlanRouteActivity﹕ Route: {   "routes" : [],   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"}
02-23 08:54:02.117  25055-25055/de.bmw.ceprouteguide D/PlanRouteActivity﹕ Google Directions status code: NOT_FOUND
```

Anyone an idea where the problem is?

Comment: Could it be an encoding issue? AFAIK ß is not valid in URLs.

Comment: @immibis That was the problem, thanks for the fast response! I had to replace "ß" with "ss" and "ü" with "ue" and now it works. Please post your solution so that I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have API key
you have to enable API from https://console.developers.google.com

1. Google Maps Direction API
2. Google Maps Android API

If not create credentials to access your enable API.

wait for 10 min and then retry.